# github jenkins webhook expecting a jenkins job that has been deleted

Tags: jenkins, github, git-webhooks

I have set up Github with a Jenkins (GitHub plugin) integration/service and webhooks (one for push only, one for specified events including comments). I am replacing an old Jenkins "project" (aka job) with a new one that is programmatically generated. For a period of time we had both Jenkins jobs configured to listen for Github events in this repo, but I deleted the old Jenkins job and now there is only one. However, Github is still looking for a report from the old job and is also marking it "REQUIRED". (Nobody can figure out what causes it to consider the one job required and not the other one, either.)

How do I make Github stop looking for the deleted Jenkins job?

Here's a screencap of part of the github page:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Repository settings -> Branches -> Protected branches -> select a branch. Then check new Jenkins job, uncheck old one:

[image]